# How to fix 400 Bad Request with empty filter query in RestHeart?

Tags: rest, query-string, restheart

I am using Restheart and MongoDB. And I am calling one service(API) for the response data.

**Working API**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/donor?filter="{'name':'john'}"
```

When I calling above API then it is working, But When I putted API filter is empty, Like filter={} then it is not working.

**Not Working API**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/donor?filter="{}"
```

When I calling API with empty filter="{}", Then its giving me **400 Bad Request**

Actually I wan to achieve one API Call for two purpose.

> 1. One for with filter condition.
> 2. Second one without filter condition.

**I want to call Like below.**

```
    var qryFilter = {}; 
    var qryFilterParam; 
    qryFilter["color.code"] = dateInParameter.code;
    qryFilterParam = '&filter=' + JSON.stringify(qryFilter)
    http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/donor?qryFilterParam
```

Then some time ***qryFilterParam*** have value and some time don't have. When Its have values like filter="{'name':'john'}" then it is working but when it's don't have key value like filter="{}" then it is not working. I am searching solution on website http://restheart.org/curies/1.0/filter.html but I am not able find to solution.

Answer (score 1):

An empty filter is not allowed by restheart.

You need an if statement in your code to make a request with filter qparam and a request without.